# Access 2010 database with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: database, visual-studio-2010, ms-access

I have an Access 2010 database that I am trying to access in a Windows Form Visual Studio application.

Here is my code:

```
         strDB = " Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="



        strDB = strDB & pstrPathName


        ' the connection object
        mdbDatabase = New OleDbConnection(strDB)

        ' open the connection
        mdbDatabase.Open()
```

It fails to work. The Message I get is  “Microsoft.ACE,OLEDB.12.0” provider is not registered on the local machine.

I was advised in another Forum to try to install AccessDatabaseEngine.exe. That program  installed ok but it didn’t help. Any thoughts?

Bob

Comment: BTW I found this useful http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/vstsdb/thread/1d5c04c7-157f-4955-a14b-41d912d50a64

Comment: Is Access 32 bit or 64 bit? I don't know but I am running Windows 7,

Comment: It is important to know: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/24259/beginner-discover-if-youre-running-the-32-or-64-bit-version-of-office-2010/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in another Forum

1) Right Click on the Project, choose Properties
2) Choose Compile
3) Click on Advance Compile
4) Under Option, pick Target CPU
5) Chnage to x86.

Bob

Comment: In that case, it seems that the answer is 32 bit.